# Django templates: make child loop inside of a nested loop to do certain number of iterations

Tags: python, django, list, loops, django-templates

I have two lists:

```
list1 = ['a','b','c','d']
list2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
```

I want to render them into the template as follows:

```
a   1  2  3
b   4  5  6
c   7  8  9
d   10 11 12
```

So the first column with the letters (`list1`) is row indexes. Each row consists of 3 cells populated from `list2`.

Template structure is the following:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="row-index">row index from list1</div>
   <div class="cell">cell1 from list2</div>
   <div class="cell">cell2 from list2</div>
   <div class="cell">cell3 from list2</div>
</div>
```

Obviously it is not enough to do a simple nested nested loop here (for `list1` and `list2`):

```
{% for row_index in list1 %}
   <div class="row">
      <div class="row-index">{{ row_index }}</div>
      {% for cell in list2 %}
      <div class="cell">{{ cell }}</div>
      {% endfor %}
   </div>
{% endfor %}
```

This will render 4 rows (which is right!) but each row will have 12 cells instead of 3 per row.

Unfortunately, `zip_longest(list1, list2)` won't help since it adds extra `'None'` elements to `list1` to make it of equal length with `list2`. Result is 4 actual row indexes, followed by 8 empty ones. And the cells rendered are all the same for each individual row, e.g. `"a 1 1 1"`, `"b 2 2 2"`, etc.

Is there any way in Django templates to force child loop (inside the nested loop) to do only 3 iterations per 1 iteration of its parent loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the longer list into chunks. You can take your pick from the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks), for example:

```
def chunks(l, n):
    """
    Yield successive n-sized chunks from l.
    code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/312464/113962
    """
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i + n]
```

Zip the shorter list and the chunked list together.

```
list1 = ['a','b','c','d']
list2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
chunked = chunks(list2, 3)
zipped_lists = zip(list1, chunked)
```

Then loop through the zipped list in your template, for example:

```
{% for x, chunk in zipped_list %}
{{ x }} {% for y in chunk %}{{ y }} {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [the forloop counter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#for)?

```
{% for row_index in list1 %}
   <div class="row">
      <div class="row-index">{{ row_index }}</div>
      {% for cell in list2 %}
           {% if forloop.counter < 4 %}
               <div class="cell">{{ cell }}</div>
           {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
   </div>
{% endfor %}
```